# Designing issue in button

Tags: ios, xcode, web, ios7

I have one tableview and search bar in viewcontroller...I have two button in table cell...
I want to set button image but when I set it is displaying like this...I remove title of button but though it is not working

[image]

and I want output like this:

[image]

pick button is displaying blue shade. I am creating button with code.

Comment: Then show us the code!

Comment: check your autolayout property

Comment: Are you using UIButton of type "System" instead of "Custom"?

Comment: Is there a way not to have the blue tint yet use the system type of button? I need to use the system type in order to have both title and image on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
   UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(185, 100, 80, 40)];
   [button setTitle:@"Pick" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage.png"];
   [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   [self.view addSubview:button];
```